# Display a JSON field with AngularJS from Golang REST service

Tags: json, angularjs, go

On the server, I have the following simple Go REST function:

```
func GetFoo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

res1D := &Response1{
    Page:   101,
    Fruits: []string{"apple", "peach", "pear"},
}
res1B, _ := json.Marshal(res1D)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/json; charset=utf-8")
w.Write(res1B)

}

type Response1 struct {
Page   int
Fruits []string
}
```

On my index.html, my AngularJS code is:

```
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
{{allFoo}}
<div ng-repeat="foo in allFoos">
    {{foo}}
</div>
```

And my AngularJS controller:

```
function SecondCtrl($scope, Restangular){

var foos = Restangular.all('rest/foos');

foos.getList().then(function(foo) {
    $scope.allFoos = foo;
});
};
```

When index.html is rendered, for {{allFoos}} I see:

```
{"0":101,"1":["apple","peach","pear"],"Page":101,"Fruits":["apple","peach","pear"],"route":"rest/foos","parentResource":null,"restangularCollection":true}
```

And for the repeat AngularJS div, for {{foo}}, I get:

```
101
["apple","peach","pear"]
["apple","peach","pear"]
101
true
rest/foos
```

My objective is to only display the "Page" field of Response1.
I tried {{foo.Page}} in the repeat div, but then the repeat div does not display anything, and I do not see an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{allFoo.Page}}`. Your `ng-repeat` is looping over the values of `allFoos`, which is why you see `Page`'s value, `101`, in that list.

Comment: I am now only getting the 'Page' field, thx!.....Do you know why I am getting multiple rows in the repeat area, there should only be one Foo, therefore only one 'Page'?

Comment: I'm mistaken, this is not working, per the examples I've seen, {{foo.Page}} needs to work. I need to find out how to just display "101"